# How to calculate set of day length using start and end dates when periods overlapping each other?

Tags: python, date

For Example,

- 01/01/2015 - 02/01/2015
- 03/31/2015 - 09/01/2016
- 05/31/2016 - 07/01/2016
- 06/01/2016 - 04/15/2017

How would you calculate the total length of all periods without overlapping using Python 2?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Rory, I am sorry if it looks like I don't want to do anything. I posted this question mostly because the task complexity is higher than my level. I was just hoping that someone already had experience with it and would give me at least some insight in the steps to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the question and answer from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69242/23030 we can merge overlapping dates. Then we just need to total up the differences of those intervals. I leave it to you to validate that this code does what you require.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime as dt

def merge_intervals(intervals):
    """
    A simple algorithm can be used:
    1. Sort the intervals in increasing order
    2. Push the first interval on the stack
    3. Iterate through intervals and for each one compare current interval
       with the top of the stack and:
       A. If current interval does not overlap, push on to stack
       B. If current interval does overlap, merge both intervals in to one
          and push on to stack
    4. At the end return stack
    """
    sorted_by_lower_bound = sorted(intervals, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    merged = []

    for higher in sorted_by_lower_bound:
        if not merged:
            merged.append(higher)
        else:
            lower = merged[-1]
            # test for intersection between lower and higher:
            # we know via sorting that lower[0] <= higher[0]
            if higher[0] <= lower[1]:
                upper_bound = max(lower[1], higher[1])
                merged[-1] = (lower[0], upper_bound)  # replace by merged interval
            else:
                merged.append(higher)
    return merged

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [(dt.date(2015,1,1),dt.date(2015,2,1)), 
         (dt.date(2015,3,31),dt.date(2015,9,1)), 
         (dt.date(2016,5,31),dt.date(2016,7,1)),  
         (dt.date(2016,6,1),dt.date(2017,4,15))]
    print("Original list of ranges: {}".format(l))
    merged_list = merge_intervals(l)
    print("List of ranges after merge_ranges: {}".format(merged_list))

    total_length = 0
    for i,j in merged_list:
        total_length += abs(j - i).days

    print('total length in days: {}'.format(total_length))
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)